# AWS SQS error while receiving message from queue in Java with message attributes

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, messaging, spring-messaging

I am sending a message using AmazonSQS.

AmazonSQS client:

```
 var sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(
            buildEndpointConfiguration( configuration ) )
        .withCredentials( buildCredentialsProvider( configuration ) )
        .build();
```

Set attributes:

```
    var attributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();

    headers.forEach( ( key, value ) -> {
        var headerValue = new MessageAttributeValue()
            .withStringValue( value )
            .withDataType( "String" );

        attributes.put( key, headerValue );
    } );
```

Make a request:

```
   var request = new SendMessageRequest()
        .withQueueUrl( eventQueueEndpoint )
        .withMessageBody( messageBody )
        .withMessageAttributes( attributes );
```

Result:

```
var result = sqs.sendMessage( request );
```

After I set message attributes, got errors. The errors while testing with testcontainers [Testcontainers Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack)

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to unmarshall response (Encountered unexpected event: [Stax Event #12]). Response Code: 200, Response Text: 

at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1750)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleSuccessResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1446)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Encountered unexpected event: [Stax Event #12]
at com.amazonaws.transform.StaxUnmarshallerContext.readText(StaxUnmarshallerContext.java:127)
```

How it can be fixed?

Comment: Which part of your code/setup deals with spring-messaging? Are you using any of the spring provided frameworks to integrate with AWS or.....? I mean something like spring-cloud-function - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/aws.html?

Comment: I am using 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging' dependency for messaging using SQS. Creating AmazonSQS instance manually. Because it sends to different servers.

Comment: I do not se anything in your code or stack trace even remotely pointing to anything Spring, hence my question. . .

Comment: The error while parsing xml data. Something is weird. If I set attributes it is not parsed, if send the event without attributes, no any problem with parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, After long researches, I found the answer. By default **AmazonSQS's** ***MessageAttributeValue*** class wraps attributes into **CDATA** section. While parsing it to the **XML**, the exception occurred. The way to solve this problem is using byte[] data type instead of String data type.

The correct way to create a **MessageAttributeValue** class is :

```
var attribute = new MessageAttributeValue()
        .withDataType( "Binary" )
        .withBinaryValue( ByteBuffer.wrap( message.getBytes( UTF8 ) ) );
```

The issue was with LocalStack. You can see the issue by visiting the link [Small deviation in SQS implementation](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/2626)